# More databases inside the same Firebase Project

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In the new Console in a Firebase Project, in **Project Setting** session in the **Database tab** there is the label **Databases**.

However I didn't find any action to create more than 1 database inside the same Firebase Project.

Is it possible to create more databases inside the same Firebase Project?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Multi-database** is a new feature that allows you to create multiple database instances.

To get started you need to be in the **Blaze plan.** In the data viewer you can click the triple dot icon to create new database instances:

[image]

To access data from a secondary instance you use an absolute URL when creating a database instance.

```
const app = firebase.initializeApp({
  // use your main config
  databaseUrl: "https://multi-db.firebaseio.com/"
});
const db1 = app.database(); // This is the default DB
const db2 = app.database("https://multi-db501c7.firebaseio.com/");
```

Since these databases are in the same project they share the same Authentication session.

Also each database instance has its own set of security rules and the databases can handle different structures.

Comment: I'm getting an error: "FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Database initialized multiple times. Please make sure the format of the database URL matches with each database() call. " when I try this. Currently using v4.12.1

Comment: is there any update on this?  I have also tried 

    var serviceAccount = require(__dirname + "/xxxx.json");
    var serviceAccount2 = require(__dirname + "/xxxx.json");

    admin.initializeApp({
   credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
   databaseURL: "https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com"});


    admin_db_2.initializeApp({
   credential: admin_db_2.credential.cert(serviceAccount2),
   databaseURL: "https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com"
    });

but not working....

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti, can you create more than one Firestore Database in the same project?

Comment: @gabriele is this possible in the Firestore database?

Comment: Firestore database scales automatically. We need sharding in the Realtime database.

Answer (score 5):

You can only have one Database per project at this time. You can create multiple projects, each with its own database instance, and use them within a single app, but you'll need to create a separate FirebaseApp (FIRApp on iOS) instance in your code for each database.

Comment: Can you please clarify whats the difference between Single App and Project?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix using as follow

```
var serviceAccount = require(__dirname + "/xxxx.json");


admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://mydb1.firebaseio.com"
});


let app = admin.app();
let ref = app.database('https://mydb2.firebaseio.com').ref();
```

and then to access another db

```
var appVersionRefDev = ref.child('/child');
```