# Multiple databases in Firebase project

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On Firebase pricing page it has been stated that:

> What is a "simultaneous database connection"?
>
> A simultaneous connection is equivalent to one mobile device, browser tab, or server app connected to the database. Firebase imposes hard limits on the number of simultaneous connections to your app's database. These limits are in place to protect both Firebase and our users from abuse.
>
> The Spark plan limit is 100 and cannot be raised. The Flame and Blaze plans have a limit of 100,000 simultaneous connections per database. If you need more than 100,000 simultaneous connections, contact Firebase support.
>
> This limit isn't the same as the total number of users of your app, because your users don't all connect at once. **We encourage you to monitor your peak simultaneous database connections and upgrade or add more databases if needed.**

On the last paragraph, what does it mean by adding more databases? Because as far as I know there is only one database in a project and multiple nodes inside that database. Does it mean creating multiple projects?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37365214/more-databases-inside-the-same-firebase-project/47427984#47427984

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it means having a separate project as you can only have 1 database per project.

**Update (2018 - 2019):**

As of writing, Firebase now supports multiple Realtime Database instances per project. The database limits are now 100 for Spark, 200**K** for Flame and 200**K** ***per database*** for Blaze.

Comment: I saw the option to add a database in the same project if we have blaze plan. Idk what to think anymore

Comment: This answer is not true, at least not any longer. @Siyas answer should be the accepted answer

Comment: @iamL answer updated to reflect multiple Realtime Database support

Comment: is there a significant speed difference when using more than one database in an app?

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple FirebaseApp instances. One will be initialised by default from the json file values, and the other you can create yourself, e.g.

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
   .setApplicationId("1:530266078999:android:481c4ecf3253701e") // Required for Analytics.
   .setApiKey("AIzaSyBRxOyIj5dJkKgAVPXRLYFkdZwh2Xxq51k") // Required for Auth.
   .setDatabaseUrl("https://project-1765055333176374514.firebaseio.com/") //Required for RTDB.
   .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this /* Context */, options, "secondary"); // 
Retrieve my other app.
FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("secondary");
// Get the database for the other app.
FirebaseDatabase secondaryDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(app);
```